# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <div>

Tags: next.js, hydration

Here is a simple code where I am fetching data from an api. It is keep pushing "Hydration Error".

[image: 1]

```
import Image from "next/image";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Suspense, use } from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

async function loadMovies() {
  const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=70b45bfec667a0c7cbfbad1a496bc748`;
  const data = await fetch(url);
  if (!data.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  const res = await data.json()
  let titles = []
  res.results.map((data) => {
    titles.push(data.title)
  })
  return titles;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const titles = await loadMovies()
  console.log(titles);


  return (
    
      <div>
        <p>Movies</p>
      {titles.map((title, index) => {
          return(<p key={index}>{title}</p>);       
      })}
      </div>
  
  );
}
```

How to avoid the hydration error. No matter what I write in div or p tag there, it pushes hydration failed.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently it'll work in build deployment, I think the issue could be because

- You're placing p tag inside another p tag.
- NextJS is SSR framework and building html content from client side like this throws similar errors

Also I suggest instead of making your component async use this pattern

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

async function loadMovies() {
  const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=70b45bfec667a0c7cbfbad1a496bc748`;
  const data = await fetch(url);
  if (!data.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  const res = await data.json()
  let titles = []
  res.results.map((data) => {
    titles.push(data.title)
  })
  return titles;
}

export default function Home() {
  
  const [titles, setTitles] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadMovies().then(t => setTitles(t))
  },[])

  return (
    
      <div>
        <p>Movies</p>
      {titles.map((title, index) => {
          return(<p key={index}>{title}</p>);       
      })}
      </div>
  
  );
}
```

[image]